# Passing multiple parameters via a url in MVC framework

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters in a url that looks like this...

```
http://somedomain.com/lessons/lessondetails/5/3
```

... to a function in the controller that looks like this ...

```
class LessonsController extends Controller

{
public function lessonDetails($studentId, $editRow=NULL)
{
    try {
        $studentData = new StudentsModel();
        $student = $studentData->getStudentById((int)$studentId);
        $lessons = $studentData->getLessonsByStudentId((int)$studentId);

        if ($lessons)
        {
            $this->_view->set('lessons', $lessons);

        } 
        else
        {
            $this->_view->set('noLessons', 'There are no lessons currently scheduled.');
        }
        $this->_view->set('title', $student['first_name']);
        $this->_view->set('student', $student);

        return $this->_view->output();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Application error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

But only the first parameter seems to pass successfully.
Not sure what to copy and paste here but here's the bootstrap.php...

```
$controller = "students";
$action = "index";
$query = null;

if (isset($_GET['load']))
{
    $params = array();
    $params = explode("/", $_GET['load']);

    $controller = ucwords($params[0]);

    if (isset($params[1]) && !empty($params[1]))
    {
            $action = $params[1];
    }

    if (isset($params[2]) && !empty($params[2]))
    {
            $query = $params[2];
    }
}

$modelName = $controller;
$controller .= 'Controller';
$load = new $controller($modelName, $action);

if (method_exists($load, $action))
{
    $load->{$action}($query);
}
else
{
    die('Invalid method. Please check the URL.');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...what is your question? What is not working as expected? What MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Show us your routing code.

Comment: Based on the `htaccess` it looks like you are using Zend Framework. It's a problem in your `routing` not your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Oops sorry. With the code above only the first parameter passes to the function successfully.

Comment: Exactly, to be able to help you we need to see your defined routes.

Comment: Zend framework, as well as most other common frameworks, would rewrite to only index.php (without load=$1) and handle the requested URL from PHP. This looks like something homecooked. We need to see your routing or know what framework you are using to help. Everything is passed from your rewrite rule..

Comment: The URL looks like this http://somedomain.com/lessons/lessondetails/5/3

Comment: That's not what we asked, see my answer below please. You need to pass us your routing definitions. Not the url. Your routes are most likely defined in your `Bootstrap.php` file.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm not sure what to look for in terms of routing. I updated the original message with the bootstrap.php file.

Comment: From a comment on the answer below it sounds that @user226433 is not using Zend.

Answer (score -1):

Call `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` from your action controller and check if both parameters are there.

If NO, the problem lies with your routing.

If YES, the problem lies with passing the parameters to your controller method `lessonDetails`.

Also, `lessondetailsAction` is missing. (this will be the method called if you visit the url you posted)

Comment: Actually, I'm not using Zend. It's an MVC I pulled from a tutorial (http://www.domagojsalopek.com/Details/Create-a-simple-PHP-MVC-Framework/28)

I'm not exactly sure what else to show you...